# How to reference the same Model twice from another one?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, foreign-keys, google-cloud-datastore

The following code

```
class Translation(db.Model):
    origin = db.ReferenceProperty(Expression, required=True)
    target = db.ReferenceProperty(Expression, required=True)
```

produces the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 4053, in _HandleRequest
>       self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3977, in _Dispatch
>       base_env_dict=env_dict)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 588, in Dispatch
>       base_env_dict=base_env_dict)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3050, in Dispatch
>       self._module_dict)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2954, in ExecuteCGI
>       reset_modules = exec_script(handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2834, in ExecuteOrImportScript
>       exec module_code in script_module.**dict**
>     File "D:\svn\language\Web\src\controller.py", line 5, in 
>       from model import *
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1505, in Decorate
>       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2450, in load_module
>       return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1505, in Decorate
>       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2339, in FindAndLoadModule
>       description)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 1505, in Decorate
>       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2282, in LoadModuleRestricted
>       description)
>     File "D:\svn\language\Web\src\model.py", line 24, in 
>       class Translation(db.Model):
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db__init__.py", line 500, in **init**
>       _initialize_properties(cls, name, bases, dct)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db__init__.py", line 415, in _initialize_properties
>       attr.**property_config**(model_class, attr_name)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db__init__.py", line 3461, in **property_config**
>       self.collection_name))
>   DuplicatePropertyError: Class Expression already has property translation_set

How to circumvent this limitation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Translation(db.Model):
    origin = db.ReferenceProperty(Expression, required=True, collection_name='translation_origins')
    target = db.ReferenceProperty(Expression, required=True, collection_name='translation_targets')
```

Comment: Maybe you didn't got to see the timestamps - my answer was written in 5 minutes after the question was asked - it was the first answer to the question, it solved OP problem. There was no time for extra explanations - are other answers which are doing that, I don't like seeing duplicated stuff

Comment: So, basically, you raced to say 'First!', and then left others to provide high quality answers?

Comment: yeah, basically, I raced to give him a solution to his problem in order to free him of the frustrations generated by a code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 11):

Give distinct collection names

```
class Translation(db.Model):
    origin = db.ReferenceProperty(Expression, required=True,collection_name='origin_translation_set')
    target = db.ReferenceProperty(Expression, required=True,collection_name='target_translation_set')
```

every db.ReferenceProperty by default creates a collection named referencedmodelname_set  in the referred model.

For eg:

```
class OwnedCar(db.Model):
   brand  =  db.StringProperty(required=True)
   owner  =  db.ReferenceProperty(Human, required=True)

class Human(db.Model):
    name    = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    drives  = db.ReferenceProperty(reference_class=Car)
```

Every Human by default will have an attribute called ownedcar_set by default. If you are referring to the same model twice, this creates the collection_name conflict. So you should add collection_name to differentiate the collections.

More reference [here](http://daily.profeth.de/2008/04/er-modeling-with-google-app-engine.html)

Answer (score 5):

Give them distinct collection names:

```
class Translation(db.Model):
    origin = db.ReferenceProperty(Expression, required=True,
                                  collection_name='origin_translation_set')
    target = db.ReferenceProperty(Expression, required=True,
                                  collection_name='target_translation_set')
```